# Yii2 - Where clause for 1:M relation

Tags: yii2

I have 2 tables :

### Product Option Group

```
 id |  opt_name  | active_flag
------------------------------
  1 | Cook level |     0
```

---

### Product Option List

```
 id | optgrp_id | list_name | active_flag
------------------------------------------
  1 |     1     |     25    |     0
  2 |     1     |     50    |     1
  3 |     1     |     75    |     0
  4 |     1     |    100    |     0
```

---

### Product Option Group Model

```
public function getOptList()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProdOptlist::className(),['optgrp_id'=>'id']);
}
```

---

### Product Option List Model

```
public function getOptGrp()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProdOptgrp::className(),['id'=>'optgrp_id']);
}
```

---

### Product Option Group Controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
    {
        ...
    }
    else
        return $this->render('update', ['model'=>$model]);
}

protected function findModel($id)
{
   if (($model = ProdOptgrp::find()
                    ->joinWith('optList')
                    ->where([ProdOptgrp::tableName().'.id'=>$id, 
                        ProdOptgrp::tableName().'.active_flag'=>0, 
                        ProdOptlist::tableName().'.active_flag'=>0])
                    ->one()) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

---

### Update View

Expected output for print_r($model->optList) :

```
{
    [id] => 1
    [optgrp_id] => 1
    [list_name] => 25
    [active_flag] => 0
},
{
    [id] => 3
    [optgrp_id] => 1
    [list_name] => 75
    [active_flag] => 0
},
{
    [id] => 4
    [optgrp_id] => 1
    [optList_name] => 100
    [active_flag] => 0
}
```

Actual output :

```
{
    [id] => 1
    [optgrp_id] => 1
    [list_name] => 25
    [active_flag] => 0
},
{
    [id] => 2
    [optgrp_id] => 1
    [list_name] => 50
    [active_flag] => 1
},
{
    [id] => 3
    [optgrp_id] => 1
    [list_name] => 75
    [active_flag] => 0
},
{
    [id] => 4
    [optgrp_id] => 1
    [optList_name] => 100
    [active_flag] => 0
}
```

Yii2 debugger showing correct query but output still consist of all 4 elements. 
Kindly advice if there is any mistake, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you use the `joinWith()` the `where()` part of your `$model = ProdOptgrp::find()...` code only limits the result that is returned by the query executed by `one()` method call. It doesn't affect what is loaded for relations.

If you want to limit what is loaded for relations you can do it:

**1) By modifing the existing relation**

This is the solution you've come to. You add the where condition directly to the `getOptList()` method of your `ProdOptgrp` model. If you do it this way, the `$model->optList` will always return filtered relation. Depending on case that might be advantage or disadvantage.

**2) By adding second relation**

You can create another method in your `ProdOptgrp` model that will define the filtered relation while keeping the original `getOptList()` unfiltered.
For example like this:

```php
class ProdOptgrp extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function getOptList()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProdOptlist::className(),['optgrp_id'=>'id']);
    }

    public function getFilteredOptList()
    {
        return $this->getOptList()->where([            
            ProdOptlist::tableName() . '.active_flag' => 0
        ]);
    }
}
```

In this case the `$model->optList` will still contain unfiltered OptLists and the `$model->filteredOptList` will contain filtered. This solution is good when you need to use both at different spots of your application.

**3) By using callback syntax in joinWith() or with()**

In case you want to filter the relation only in one particular case you don't need to modify your model. You can modify the relation with callback that is called before loading the data.

```php
$model = ProdOptgrp::find()
    ->joinWith([
        'optList' => function(\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
            $query->where([
                ProdOptlist::tableName() . '.active_flag' => 0
            ]);
        }
    ])->where([
        ProdOptgrp::tableName().'.id'=>$id, 
        ProdOptgrp::tableName().'.active_flag'=>0,
        ProdOptlist::tableName() . '.active_flag'=>0, 
    ])->one();
```

The last condition in `where()` will cause the $model to be null when the active_flag is 0 in optgrp table but 1 in all related records in optlist table. I'm not sure if that is inteded behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer Michal! I am definitely learned lots from your answer :D Have a nice day and stay inspired! ;D

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way too:

//Controller

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
   if (($model = ProdOptgrp::findOne($id)) !== null && $model->isActive()) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

//Model

```
/*
*Check if model is active
*/
public function isActive(){
    return ($this->active_flag == 0) ? true: false;
}

public function getOptList()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProdOptlist::className(),['optgrp_id'=>'id'])->where([ProdOptgrp::tableName().'.active_flag'=>0]);
}
```

//View

```
foreach($model->optList as optItem): // you get filtered result
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately I still couldn't get it right with the error of **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'prod_optgrp.active_flag' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `prod_optlist` WHERE (`prod_optgrp`.`active_flag`=0) AND (`optgrp_id`=1).**
Seems like this error come from **public function getOptList()**.

Comment: I got this solved by doing a minor changes to the function getOptList(), edit the return to $this->hasMany(ProdOptlist::className(),['optgrp_id'=>'id'])->where([ProdOptlist::tableName().'.active_flag'=>0]). It's working like charm now! Thank you Serghei ;)